# Numbers in javascript clarification?

Tags: javascript

If

```
(10) instanceof Number
```

returns false, then why does

```
(10).constructor
```

return [Function : Number]?

Update: I see now what happens, but this behaviour was obviously designed into the language. I can understand the benefit of, say, allowing implicit conversion of "4" to 4, but is there a tangible advantage to implicitly converting primitives into objects?

Comment: I think because expression (10) is `number`, which is not `Number`, but method call implicitly converts it to Object Number.

Comment: Just how javascript treats primitives... it has a history its the same case with `"" instanceof String`